# Service broker cpu use issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service, broker

I have created `service broker` but when I enable it my CPU usage is going near `100%` and as soon as I remove my queue and service and disable `service broker` from `SQL server` my CPU usage is again go to normal near `50%` to `60%`.

Could anyone expalain what is causing this issue with?

Comment: Do you have activation on the queue? Ice seen similar behavior when I had an internally activated procedure that want written correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Basicallu, if there is only `Reporting Workload` on the server the SQL Server instance will use all available CPU (if needed).

You can use `CAP_CPU_PERCENT` to cap on the CPU bandwidth that all requests in the resource pool will receive([official documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895329.aspx)).

```
-- Creating Resource Pool for Report Server
CREATE RESOURCE POOL ReportServerPool
WITH
( MIN_CPU_PERCENT=0,
MAX_CPU_PERCENT=30,
CAP_CPU_PERCENT=40,
MIN_MEMORY_PERCENT=0,
MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT=30)
GO
```

You can find more details [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/09/sql-server-service-broker-and-cap_cpu_percent-limiting-sql-server-instances-to-cpu-usage/).